# Maven pulls antlr jar which does not show in dependency:tree

Tags: java, maven, antlr

I have multiple versions of `antlr` in my Maven / Java project and I am trying to understand which dependency in the project's `pom.xml` is pulling which version.

Under my .m2 directory I see three different `antlr` versions:

```
~/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.2/antlr-2.7.2.jar
~/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar
~/.m2/repository/.../org.apache.servicemix.bundles.antlr-2.7.7_5.jar
```

If I run

```
$ mvn dependency:tree
```

from the project's root directory, I get:

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.directory.api:api-all:jar:2.0.0.AM2:compile
[INFO] |  +- ...:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.antlr:jar:2.7.7_5:compile
...
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-agroal:pom:5.3.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.agroal:agroal-pool:jar:0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.3.7.Final:compile
...
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
```

So, Maven finds version `2.7.7_5` (pulled by `org.apache.directory.api:api-all`) and version `2.7.7` (pulled by `org.hibernate:hibernate-agroal`) but no version `2.7.2`. This version is not listed in the project `pom.xml` directly.

I deleted the folder `.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.2` and ran

```
$ mvn compile
```

from the project's root folder. This immediately downloaded version 2.7.2 again:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/antlr/antlr/2.7.2/antlr-2.7.2.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/antlr/antlr/2.7.2/antlr-2.7.2.pom (145 B at 331 B/s)
```

And, again, `mvn dependency:tree` shows nothing about version 2.7.2. How can this be? Why does mvn pull a JAR-version that does not show in the project's dependencies? How to find out which dependency in the `pom.xml` file is pulling this JAR-file?

I have been searching the documentation for the past three hours but I have no clue at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

Dependencies can also come from plugins, try running `dependency:resolve-plugins` to resolve all plugins along with their dependencies:

```
mvn dependency:resolve-plugins
```

Besides that, the other thing you can probably do is run `mvn` with `-X` option for debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. (+1)  On the command-line the version is pulled by some maven plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Two main possibilities:

- if only the POM appears in `.m2/repository`, then this is just part of the dependency resolution process of Maven.
- if the POM and the JAR appear, and the JAR is not in the dependency tree, then it is likely that a maven plugin pulls the JAR into `.m2/repository`.

Generally, there is nothing to worry if you find unexpected JARs in your local repository.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The problem is that Hibernate then picks the wrong version and throws an exception. So if it is a plugin, I would like to find out which one: maybe I can upgrade that plugin and it will use a newer version of the library.

Comment: But how can hibernate pick a version from the local repository? This seems strange. The local repository is just a cache, it is not on your classpath.

Comment: OK. I have to go step back: the error occurs when debugging in Eclipse. Since Eclipse is getting its project dependencies from the `pom.xml` file via a Maven plugin, I assumed that the dependencies used within Eclipse should be the same as those reported by Maven. So I used Maven on the command line to show the dependencies.

Comment: And, yes, in the command line, version `2.7.2` is pulled by two Maven plugins.

Comment: Are you debugging inside the Maven build?

Comment: > Are you debugging inside the Maven build?
I am not sure what you mean exactly. I have created an Eclipse project from a maven project: the two share the same directory. I then created debug configuration in Eclipse and started a main class. Hibernate throws an exception `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: antlr.collections.AST.getLine()I
   at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.generateNamedParameter(HqlSqlWalker.java:1167)
   at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.parameter(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3416)`

Comment: This happens irregularly, sometimes it occurs, sometimes it does not. My theory was that Hibernate is picking the wrong antlr version.